# How to find a specific slime chunk pattern in Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm playing Bedrock Edition and I want a specific pattern of slime chunks in my world. I don't know how to do it. In Bedrock, slime chunks are predefined for a set of coordinate. Is there any apps?

Answer (score 1):

If you know your world seed, here is a [Slime Finder](https://www.chunkbase.com/apps/slime-finder) webpage.

Comment: Out of curiousity, cause I'm having trouble finding slimes, is this considered cheating to the majority of the minecraft community, or is it it accepted?  I know it's up to the player to decide, but I'm genuinely curious what the consensus is.

Comment: @Millard imho using seed to locate Strongholds, Woodland mansions, Ocean temples, End Cities **is** cheating, but slime is a renewable source and I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: I need to find slime chunk configuration, like a square of 9x9 slime chunks

Comment: @JRBros it will be **very** unlikely to have that configuration: a chunk has 1/10 chance to be a slime chunk, and having 81 one near another is quite impossible. It's easier to find an End portal completely filled by default.